# How to run aws-nuke without providing inputs during execution?

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-nuke

I'm trying to run https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke ans pass answers to interactive prompts. Script is asking for alias of an account (twice).
Unfortunately it passes only first answer, second is omitted. Error I got:

> Do you want to continue? Enter account alias to continue.
>   Error: EOF

Function is in AWS Lambda:

```
command='/tmp/aws-nuke -c /tmp/config.yml --no-dry-run --access-key-id '+newsession_id+' --secret-access-key '+newsession_key+' --session-token '+newsession_token+'''<< EOF 
    alias
    alias
    EOF'''

    popen = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am a maintainer of aws-nuke. You do not need to dynamically provide the requested input. When adding the `--force` flag, it won't ask you, but simply waits some seconds as a safety measurement.